# Multidimensional arrays as class member with arbitrary bounds

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax, instantiation

Not a duplicate of [C++: multidimensional array initialization in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975215/c-multidimensional-array-initialization-in-constructor) since the answers all *appear* to assume the bounds are known at compile-time.

I'm making a weighted undirected graph class `arraygraph`, backed by a 2D array of `int`, by the name of `edges[][]`. At instantiation time I don't really care what `edges[][]` holds; `arraygraph` has a method that reads a graph from a given filename and `edges` is set to a `new int[n][n]` (where `n` is the # of nodes in the file) by that function before it populates it.

Trouble is, g++ doesn't seem to like the way I've defined `edges[][]`. It wants to have set bounds for the array, and at compile time I don't *know* the bounds. Should I just redefine `edges` as an `int *`? Or as `edges[][0]`? Or something else entirely?

I'm not a C++ expert by any means (I'm a Python kinda guy) so complex, heavyweight options like the ones in [Array with undefined size as Class-member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135093/array-with-undefined-size-as-class-member) are kinda out of scope (surely there's a simpler way than *that*...). If what I'm trying to do is a wrong thing entirely than that's also a useful thing to know, and it'd be handy to know what I ought to be doing instead.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29055366/365496) answer your question? It only discusses two dimensional arrays, but it applies to any rectangular arrays (i.e., arrays where for each dimension, each element has the same size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't know variable length arrays.  So you need to define your array with a constant size.  It's not possible either to redefine an array.

Two options for your multidimensional array:

- dynamic array of arrays, implemented as  `int **edges`
- std::vector instead  aka `vector<vector<int>> edges;`

vectors are extremely handy if you need to copy your data (done in a single statement), or change the sizes. So I'd recommend the second option :

```
int N=10; // dynamic! 
vector<vector<int>> m(N, vector<int>(N));
```

The alterative for using the pointer would be:

```
int N=10; // dynamic! 
int**m = new int*[N];    // allocate the first array 
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {  // allocate the second arrays
    m[i] = new int[N]{};
}
```

In both case, you'd access the data with the same syntax:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        cout << m[i][j] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `vector<vector<int>>` works but is generally not the best idea for rectangular arrays; it uses more memory and allocations than necessary.

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, but is there any trick to adding values to those vectors? Does it just make a slot for me every time I write to a new index (I'll only be writing once and doing so from 1 to `n`, if that matters)? Or do I have to tell it "Redimension yourself to be this big" before I write to it?

Comment: @bames53 Life's short, DIMM's cheap. :P

Comment: Oh, and it'd be handy to know that I need to `#include <vector>` to get a hold of `vector`.

Comment: @Schilcote It's not just using more memory; The fact that the memory is not contiguous also means it may be significantly slower. It's also more error prone and less readable, if you want rectangular arrays.

Comment: The syntax in the demo above creates automatically all your N by N entries.  You can resize() each vector as you want, later.  Or you could just create a bigger vector as above and assign it to overwrite your old one.

Comment: @bames if you use an `int**` you have no contiguity either.

Comment: @Christophe That's true. I would not recommend `int**` either. Instead I'd suggest something along [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29055366/365496).

Comment: @bames53 yes, flattening the array is also an alternative (+1 on the linked answer).  But you'd need to explicitely to use the dimension in all indexing. And if code already exist for 2 dimensions, the OP would need to rewrite it.

Comment: @Christophe It's not exactly trivial, but it's possible to implement a multi-dimensional matrix template class that supports an arbitrary number of dimensions, each of runtime size, and which uses a flattened array for storage: [proof of concept](https://gist.github.com/bames53/3d23426afbf47dc62514). This implementation uses some C++17 features but works with the current in-dev clang 3.7.

Comment: @bames53 It's a very interesting idea !

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for sort of dynamic size array. Try using  [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of the array.