# Segfault upon instantiation of object with vector<vector<int> > member

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

In [Multidimensional arrays as class member with arbitrary bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310863/multidimensional-arrays-as-class-member-with-arbitrary-bounds) I was advised I should use a vector of vectors of ints to represent a dynamic 2D array in my array-backed graph object. However, I'm getting segmentation faults whenever I try to run my code. GDB points to the line where a variable is defined as the `arraygraph` type; I presume that means I did something wrong specifying the type of `edges`. Here is the class definition:

```
class arraygraph {
private:

public:
    void open(char *filename);
    bool exists(int nodeid);
    int node_count(void);
    int weight(int nodea, int nodeb);
    void print();
private:
    int count;
    vector <vector <int> > edges; //A vector of vectors! [Inception Noise]
};
```

All the methods of this object are defined (funny how you can compile with prototypes that haven't been filled out...). The code compiles without errors or warnings. Why's it segfaulting?

EDIT:

Here's some disassembler output:

```
163       int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
          main(int, char**):
00401c86:   lea 0x4(%esp),%ecx
00401c8a:   and $0xfffffff0,%esp
00401c8d:   pushl -0x4(%ecx)
00401c90:   push %ebp
00401c91:   mov %esp,%ebp
00401c93:   push %ebx
00401c94:   push %ecx
00401c95:   sub $0x20,%esp
00401c98:   mov %ecx,%ebx
00401c9a:   call 0x402350 <__main>
164         arraygraph thegraph;
00401c9f:   lea -0x18(%ebp),%eax  (this is where the problem occured according to GDB)
00401ca2:   mov %eax,%ecx
00401ca4:   call 0x403e90 <arraygraph::arraygraph()>
```

So apparently the segfault happened before the `arraygraph` was constructed? I don't know what to make of this.

EDIT:

The entirety of `main()` is as such:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    arraygraph thegraph;
    thegraph.open(argv[1]);
    return 0; //Added this after I noticed I'd omitted it - didn't fix anything
}
```

And here's `arraygraph::open()`:

```
//Only call .open() once. A second call will leave the old graph's dessicated corpse around the edges of the new one.
void arraygraph::open(char *filename){
    int count;
    int x, y;
    tomgraph loader;

    loader.open(filename);

    count=loader.node_count();

    //delete edges;
    //edges = new vector <vector <int> >;

    for (x=1; x <= count; x++) {
        for (y=1; y <= count; y++) {
            int weight;
            if (loader.is_connected(x,y,&weight) || loader.is_connected(y,x,&weight)) {
                edges[x-1][y-1]=weight;
            } else {
                edges[x-1][y-1]=0; //0 represents "no edge"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But according to the disassembler this never gets called anyway.

EDIT:

Full code [here](http://ideone.com/nk3KN1). Umm... I think it's saying it worked? Lemme try a different machine...

EDIT:

Nope. Similar segfault after compiling on a completely separate Linux machine.

EDIT:

Just to confirm, I commented out the call to `thegraph.open()`. Didn't fix it.

Comment: You probably want a constructor for that, also can you provide the source code where the error happens? the error is not necessarily caused by the declaration but maybe the code surrounding it.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz What exactly would the constructor do? There is no code surrounding it; `arraygraph mygraph` is the first line in `main()`.

Comment: It would make sure that the object is in a defined state(ie count is 0), http://ideone.com/U3pHyg your code works as it is so the class definition is not the problem.

Comment: How does your instantiation actually look like?

Comment: Can you provide a complete compiling example that shows the problem.

Comment: @Schilcote weird, ideone.com says it works but in my computer I get a sigsegv as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never `resize` `edges` or `push_back` to it. So its size is `0` and doing `edges[x-1][y-1]` you go out of bounds. You probably have to do something like this before the loop in `arraygraph::open`:

```
edges.resize(count, std::vector<int>(count));
```

Comment: Adding resizes changes nothing. As the disasm shows, open() never gets called anyway.

Comment: @Schilcote Sometimes you have to put away the debugger and use the good old eyes.  You never sized the array before you used `[ ]`, thus you are accessing an invalid item.   If the issue isn't `open`, then remove that function altogether and see if that program actually works.  If it doesn't work, then you have a seriously broken compiler or broken standard library.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, turned out commenting out the call *did* stop the segfaults. But not the first time I tried it. Apparently GDB was just stopping on a random instruction. I just sat down and rewrote the whole thing in python today. :P